# How does battery charge limiting work when the laptop is plugged-in but hibernating?

Tags: battery

My laptop has a feature that helps enhance battery life by limiting battery charging to 60%
even while it is continuously plugged-in. I was surprised to see the limiting action in effect even after the laptop hibernated overnight while still plugged-in. I mean, if the limiting is achieved via software, then it wouldn't work during hibernation, right? Any idea how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software that achieves battery limiting will be in the [embedded system controller,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) one of the most low level parts of the system. This is not a task for the operating system.

That controller will be "on" no matter whether an operating system is running or not. It will be watching for power button presses and other events to wake. It is what allows your computer to set an alarm and wake at a specific time.

It is this controller that, if the hardware is designed for it, will be able to control and manage battery charge level.